# Find String and replace it in the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to replace the `?` question marker with `-` hyphen in the text document but it is being found but not replaced

```
Bad Schwartau ? Stockelsdorf ? ZOB/Hbf. ? Sandstr. ? Universitätsklinikum ? Grillenweg  
9
Haltestellen Montag ? Freitag
Bad Schwartau/ZOB ... 04:21 04:54 05:40 06:03 06:18 06:33 06:48 07:03 07:21 07:33 08:03 11:03
```

**Code:**

```
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int lineNum = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        lineNum++;
        if(line.contains("?")) { 
            line.replace("?", "-");
            System.out.println("I found it on line " + lineNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `line = line.replace("?", "-");`

Comment: `String.replace()` returns the value of the string with the substrings replaced. It does *not* change the original string, and most certainly does not change the file from which it was read. You'll have to write a new file with the appropriate lines, and then switch the files.

Comment: you're ignoring the return value from line.replace()

Answer (score 2):

A Java `String` is immutable - that means it cannot be changed, only replaced.

Try this instead -

```
 line = line.replace("?", "-");
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work

Comment: Hold on - what are you expecting? You're not printing out the output?

Comment: and how can I print it out? Please can you edit your answer